# Javafx Updating UI from a Thread Java 8

Tags: multithreading, javafx, java-8

I interested in one interesting task. I have UI in JavaFx with another thread which updates UI. I started updates from Platform.runLater. Code:

```
private void startUpdateDaemon() {
    updateUserStatus();
    updateTable();
}

private void startUpdateDaemonTask() {
    Task task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            while (true) {
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    startUpdateDaemon();
                });
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    };
    Thread th = new Thread(task);
    th.setDaemon(true);
    th.start();
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    startUpdateDaemonTask();
}
```

Also I have place in another class where I updates UI:

```
private void startUpdateDaemonTask() {
    Task task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            while (true) {
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        updateGameStatus();
                    }
                });
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    };

    Thread th = new Thread(task);
    th.setDaemon(true);
    th.start();
}
```

So, finally I have two places with call "Platform.runLater" and different methods inside.
My question is Can I create only "one" method with one time call "Platform.runLater" and send to this method different methods which will be call ?? May be I can write finish method with consumers and send to him methods 'startUpdateDaemon()' and 'updateGameStatus()'?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a `Runnable` parameter to your method. This parameter is given to you `Platform.runLater`:

```
private void startUpdateDaemonTask(Runnable runner) {
    Task task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            while (true) {
                Platform.runLater(runner);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    };

    Thread th = new Thread(task);
    th.setDaemon(true);
    th.start();
}
```

Now you can invoke this method with your method references:

```
startUpdateDaemonTask(this::startUpdateDaemon);
startUpdateDaemonTask(this::updateGameStatus);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Good way. That's what I need.